# Is it possible to use environment variables from “.env” in packages section of the “Pipfile”

Tags: environment-variables, pipenv

I have to use limited credentials to be able to install my packages from the private repository but I wish not to commit them with my `Pipile`.

Here is a simple legitimate use case:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
pytest = "*"

[packages]
my-package = {git = "https://${USER}:${TOKEN}@bitbucket.org/my-team/my-package.git",ref = "v0.1"}

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

[scripts]
show-credentials = "echo ${USER}:${TOKEN}"
```

And having in `.env` file this content:

```
USER=foo
TOKEN=bar
```

Executing `pipenv run show-credentials` will show current credentials as `foo:bar` but won’t respect these environment variables for installing `my-package`.

Is there any possible workaround or it might be a good feature request for the `pipenv`?

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear from the documentation but from testing it appears .env is only read during `pipenv run` and `pipenv shell`. It's not run during `pipenv sync` or `pipenv install`.

I say this because it doesn't appear to inject into the [[source]] section unless the environment variables are set outside the virtual env... i.e. `USER=my_user TOKEN=my_token pipenv install`

Comment: Thanks, that’s correct and I’ve figured it out after the question. There is an almost one-year-old issue [3516](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3516) that does not lose it's interest according to the latest duplicate issue [4038](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4038) and authors are still silent. Guess maybe in 5 years we’ll see some response to that.

Answer (score 0):

In the doc tells that you can https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html

but I tried and fails I put a Github issue because doesnt work https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5033

Pipenv fails if you put ${user}:${password} but not ${userpassword}

Comment: Oh... it's been a while since I've asked. I've should remember to post my solution. I've left Pipenv since then and moved to Poetry and suggest doing the same for everyone. But anyway the proper solution is NOT to use environment variables in git URLs in Pipenv/Poetry/requierments.txt at all but to use git config url/insteadOf in order to avoid credential leakage in locks files.

Comment: lock file doesn't keep the password in pipfile, keep the env var, that should be the same in all environment.

Comment: Nice to know it is no longer an issue but this solution is universal and much more advantageous. First of all, I am no longer need to remember which ENV vars I've used in which URL when I published the built package. Also I can specify different tokens per each repo in a single config without the need for some OS ENV vars management system. Anyway, Pipenv sucks a lot, especially as a dependency resolver where Poetry is much faster and more comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, I check poetry in the past but in general, I got a lot of errors, for simple things but I will check again.

Comment: After twenty-something times of fixing Pipenv failures with manual pip installation, not to mention 10+ minutes for resolving dependencies for the ridiculously small packages... I spotted some weaknesses in Poetry with complicated semi-circular dependencies from sources but this is nothing in comparison with day-to-day suffering (for every team member and not just me.) Anyway, this solution also relieves you in CLI from managing OS ENV variables and Poetry 1.2+ has good support for `src` layouts. And once again — 10x faster. DevOps are also, happy.

Comment: and how works with tox?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [@davegravy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2600531/davegravy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572127/is-it-possible-to-use-environment-variables-from-env-in-packages-section-of-t#answer-59746321), the `.env` file is only loaded during `pipenv run` and `pipenv shell`.

One alternative might be to call `pipenv install` from *within* the `pipenv run`. 
Like this:

```
pipenv run pipenv install
```

In this way, the `.env` will be loaded by `pipenv run`, then it will successfully executed in `pipenv run`.

Note, this method will only work if you have `pipenv` already installed *within* your existing `pipenv` environment.